# Giving error invalid syntax?

Tags: python

```
>>> a=1
>>> if a>6:
print "This is my insanity"
else:

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

> > >

I have written simple if condition to check if condition, but its giving error "invalid syntax"

Comment: when `a > 6` code prints `"This is my insanity"`, but what do you expect when `a <= 6`?

Answer (score 3):

When I do this I get an `IndentationError: expected an indented block`, not `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`. Which Python shell are you using?

The code needs to be properly indented below the `if` (like it would under a `def` etc).

Also, `else:` requires something after it ... for now you could use `pass` as a place-holder (though if you have nothing to put after the `else:`, just leave it out)

e.g.

```
a = 1
if a > 6:
   print "This is my insanity"
else:
   pass  # for now
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't leave the else block empty in your if statement:

```
>>> a = 1
>>> if a > 6:
...     print "This is my insanity"
... else:
...     print "In else block"
...
In else block
```

Comment: You can use `pass` if you don't want to do anything, or just leave out the `else` block completely.

Comment: @RadekSlupik I was assuming the OP _did_ want to do something in the else block

Answer (score 0):

Python needs proper indentation.

```
a=1
if a>6:
    print "This is my insanity"
else:
    print 'You need to have some command here as well!' # maybe try pass ?
```

Comment: Because the answer is incorrect: Indentation is **not** the problem, you can tell from the error message. See Levon's answer.

Answer (score -1):

```
a=1
if a>6:
    print "This is my insanity"
else:
    pass
```

you should not leave else as empty use pass to do nothing and there is also indentation issue(may be while posting)

Comment: You’d just **leave out the else: block**. There is no need to have one.